# Outlook does not receive email if From address is not in a recognized email format

Tags: outlook.com

I have a system to send a mail to the users who are all using different mail clients like Gmail, Outlook, Rediff etc. But, I am using a From address as constant string (`mrblack`) instead of an email format (`mrblack@example.com`).

Outlook and Rediff cannot receive these emails, while other mail servers are getting them fine.

What do I need to add/change in any header sections in my mail process (without changing from address)? Or is there any configuration in outlook.com to receive an email from a sender without the traditional email format address?

Comment: Outlook is the main issue here and keeping it focussed to that stops the question from being too broad if it has to deal with "many other" email providers @pnu

Comment: Outlook isn't sending. Outlook is having problems receiving emails where the From address doesn't contain a valid email address. @pnu

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you are using a FROM address in the form "mrblack"?

I believe that breaks RFC 2822 and so there is no guarantee that ANY client will accept it.

You need to put your FROM address text into the [correct RFC format](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822.html).